# Set of numbers given, find mean and SD of the other

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

A set of eight numbers has mean 5 and SD 4. The number 21 and another integer n are added to the set. The standard deviation of the set is now 6. Find n and the mean of the set now.

Comment: Finding the sum and the sums of squares, trying to form equations about variance.

Comment: I fooled around some and using SD equal to the square root of $(1/8)\sum(x_i-\bar{x})^2$, got an equation that seems not to give integer $n$. But it was done quickly and I am accident-prone.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to concoct $8$ numbers which have a mean of $5$ and a standard deviation of $4$.  For example, take
$$
-1,1,3,5,5,7,9,11,
$$
and label these points $x_1 , x_2, \dots , x_8$.  Then, one can easily check:
$$
\frac{1}{8}\sum_{i=1}^8 x_i  = 5
$$
and
$$
\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{8} \frac{(x_i - 5)^2}{8 - 1}} = 4.
$$

Adding $21$ and $n$ gives
$$
\mu = \frac{8 \cdot \mu_1 + 21 + n}{10} = \frac{61 + n}{10}.
$$
The new standard deviation is
$$
6 = \sigma = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{8} \frac{(x_i - \mu)^2}{10 - 1} + \frac{(21 - \mu)^2}{10 - 1} + \frac{(n - \mu)^2}{10 - 1}}.
$$
Expanding gives a quadratic equation in $\mu$:

$$\begin{align}
324 = & (-1 - \mu)^2 + (1 - \mu)^2 + (3 - \mu)^2 + 2(5 - \mu)^2 
\\
&+ (7 - \mu)^2 + (9 - \mu)^2 + (11 - \mu)^2 + (21 - \mu)^2 + (9 \mu - 61)^2
\end{align}$$
Note that the last term is $(10 \mu - 61 - \mu)^2$ as $\mu_2 = \frac{61 + n}{10}$.  Solving this for $\mu$ yields $\mu = 8$.  Hence, $n = 19$.

---

**Edit:** For clarification, this does not totally answer the question at hand.  My example does not prove that $n = 19$ is the only (integer) solution.  However, it is likely that this is the case.  The method I used to find the set of integers which worked was by noticing that we needing to find $8$ squares that sum to $112 = 4^2 \cdot (8 -1)$.  This gave a natural choice of 
$$
112 = 6^2 + 6^2 + 4^2 + 4^2 + 2^2 + 2^2 + 0^2 + 0^2
$$ 
which implied that 
$$\begin{array}{c}
 x_1 = 5 - 6
\\
 x_2 = 5 + 6
\\
 x_3 = 5 - 4
\\
 x_4 = 5+4
\\
 x_5 = 5 - 2
\\
 x_6 = 5+2
\\
 x_7 = 5 - 0
\\
 x_8 = 5 + 0
\end{array}$$  This happened to lead to a integral value of $\mu$ and therefore an integral value of $n$.

Comment: This is a proof by "My professor says it must be true", i.e., you do one example and assume it gives the same answer as any other example.

Comment: @Grapth: I never claimed that this solves the complete problem.  Your point is valid in the sense that the question has not been fully answered, but this is not a proof, and hence your comment doesn't apply.

Comment: I wonder why you are dividing by 7, and not by 8 (in your calculation of the standard deviation)? I realize there are circumstances where division by $n-1$ is correct, but I would have thought that in this case $n$ would be the correct denominator.